# Can we not delete great answers when an account is deleted by a moderator?

Tags: discussion, support, deleted-questions

A user was abusing the site and did not accept the help we gave because of lack of fundamentals from his part. A moderator deleted his account. The user created another account with the same account name and asked this question (10k+ only):

[twinsocketstream-read-read-error-6-the-handle-is-invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48196301/twinsocketstream-read-read-error-6-the-handle-is-invalid#48197264)

A high reputation user answered this question with a very long and detailed answer that is practically a solution to the whole project the deleted user was trying to do.

I have no problem with this, but the answer is just too valuable to be deleted.

And frankly, I wanted to see it again so I could read it. The answer contains more than what the question requires. It even has some great techniques that I need to study.

I thought that when an account is deleted Community get his points and owns his posts, but I do not think this is actually the case. I really need to read that answer.

Is there a way that we can restore that answer/question and give it to Community?

Comment: I wonder what would be wrong with reposting the question (cleaned up, of course), and making the entire thing Community Wiki.

Comment: @Makoto Remy's answer is much valuable to be deleted with this user. I hate to see it go away.

Comment: @Makoto What you said is true for  _votes_. Content is preserved with one exception: negatively scored posts are deleted. Unfortunately, in case the post is a question, this deletion process pays no attention to __answers__ to the question. There is a long standing request to change this behavior: [A question should not be deleted by the user deletion algorithm if it has upvoted answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/199860)

Comment: It seems the OP has re-posted the same question with a new account with the same name

Comment: @Fero because of this abuse we lose greate answers and answerers

Comment: Is the answer actually useful to other people, or it is just a code review specific to the asker's code?

Comment: @JoshCaswell in general the answer is for the question, but the way Remy coded the answer is more interesting. you can get more from an answer by studying it. this one contains best practices and some of the multithreading techniques used in connection protocols. there is 20 years of experience in that answer.

Comment: How about posting your own (good) question that would elicit that same information and either getting Remy to answer it, or reusing the material from that answer yourself, then?

Comment: @JoshCaswell I'm afraid such an approach is not welcomed now, as the deleted user has posted that question again(third time after the account was deleted) and it is currently downvoted. the deleted answer is a complete solution to a project. any new question about this will be considered Off-Topic here on SO, and I'm not interested nor in the OP's problem nor the solution, I'm interested in the way it is solved by Remy.

Comment: I didn't say you should repost the question. Ignore the original question, concentrate on the information you want to preserve. _Invent your own_ question that requires an answer that has the information you are concerned about. (This may not be possible, but I believe it's the best way forward.)

Comment: @JoshCaswell I think I'm going to work on getting 10k rep so I could access it :). thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: For what it’s worth, there are already two undelete votes on the question right now.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have cast the final un-delete vote needed to restore the question to visible status for sub-10,000 reputation users. The question is now visible and open.

There is no guarantee that it will remain undeleted, however. The long-term solution of course is to gain enough reputation of your own, so that you can view deleted content, and cast delete/undelete votes where necessary.

In the short term, if the question gets deleted again, and you/someone really needs to see the content, feel free to ask in a chatroom if a 10k user can screenshot the post for you.

Comment: If the answer is so great, then it's a shame to restrict it to deleted questions, because those don't appear in Google searches...

Comment: thank you Remy is a very talented and experienced guy, his answers are always detailed and tackle more than one side of a question. I will try to get to the 10k rep step next time.

Answer (score 7):

When an account is deleted the posts are anonymised - not assigned to community - and any votes they *gave* are removed (except in special circumstances).

There are two options when deleting an account.

1. Delete:

   > Deletes this user account, denormalizes identity on any posts they own, and deletes any negatively voted posts they own. Does not delete any content scored 0 or higher.
2. Destroy:

   > Deletes this user account and deletes all content they own. Only usable on users with less than 500 reputation.

We use the former for accounts that have "gone bad" in some way or request deletion. Using this option preserves good content. Obviously if the user asked a poorly received question (was scoring < 0) then this would be deleted regardless of the scores of any answers. I think it would be an extra burden to place on the moderator to ask them to check for cases like this. Perhaps the deletion criteria should be changed to look at the answers to questions as well.

We use the latter for spammers and trolls so all their content gets nuked along with the account.

Comment: In this case even the Delete option would have removed the question since the question was scored at -2. This is despite the fact there was a positively-scored answer on the question. I wonder if it's feasible to have Delete only remove content that would otherwise be cleaned up by the Roomba?

Comment: @TylerH That sounds like the solution we need.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification on the subject. I think TylerH's suggestion would be greate.