# Change the delete user option so that it doesn't remove questions with upvoted answers

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, deleted-questions, deleted-answers, deleted-users

An issue has been raised where a user was deleted, but potentially useful content was removed along with the account:

[Can we not delete great answers when an account is deleted by a moderator?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361835/can-we-not-delete-great-answers-when-an-account-is-deleted-by-a-moderator)

When we use the "Delete" option the following is the text we see in the dialog:

> Deletes this user account, denormalizes identity on any posts they own, and deletes any negatively voted posts they own. Does not delete any content scored 0 or higher.

However, if a negatively scoring question has positively scoring answers it's still deleted, thus removing potentially useful content from the site. As [TylerH commented](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361835/can-we-not-delete-great-answers-when-an-account-is-deleted-by-a-moderator/361874?noredirect=1#comment547855_361874):

> I wonder if it's feasible to have Delete only remove content that would otherwise be cleaned up by the Roomba?

So, my request is can this be implemented, either as a replacement for the current delete process or as an option on the process.

There's also the consistency aspect. The OP wouldn't be able to delete the question either as there's at least one upvoted answer.

Comment: Already a MSE feature request - https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/199860

Comment: So bad question gets deleted and you don't like it? So why are there good answers to bad questions? I think wrong was the moment to give an answer and do not bother with making the question matching the quality. If the question wouldn't be downvoted, it wouldn't be auto-deleted, right?

Comment: @Sinatr there are many reasons why a question might be scoring negatively but still have good answers. The main one being that it's been fixed but hasn't recovered yet. There's also the inconsistency between the way the site works - neither Roomba or the OP could delete the question so why should we as moderators (unless we explicitly want to)

Comment: Sounds like we need queue "fixed questions" then. I agree, I myself tend to upvote useful answers more than the questions. So *recovery* is indeed a problem (assuming the question is fixed). Should we fix X problem or continue with Y? What if questions get percent of upvotes to answer? Though making an exception to rules used to delete questions of removed account is more straightforward solution (read - easier).

Comment: @Sinatr A new review queue is not the answer to any problem. This feature request addresses the simple problem of good content getting inadvertently deleted in a specific use case; it doesn't need to be any more complex than that. ChrisF's example is only one example; don't fixate on trying to solve that one so narrowly that you exclude any possible other scenario.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This feature was implemented a few months ago. Quoting [Shog9's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/312594/167646) to the MSE feature request:

> So after reviewing the data, here's what I think makes sense: delete a user's posts along with them only when those posts...
>
> - ...score < 0 AND
> - ...are closed OR
> - ...have no answers scoring > 0
>
> This change is now live.