# User before and now turns into a `user` and followed by number with an empty score

Tags: support, users, deleted-users

I'm just confused why a user has no score while he/she answered the question and accepted.

As we observed, I had a comment below from the image which is `it is answered by @Stephen`. But why now, the user answered we can only see `user3559349` and also an empty score(?)

[image]

Here's the link of that [particular image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46639849/js-file-using-url-action-in-ajax-url).

Answer (score 4):

That user account was deleted, either upon request by the user themselves or by a moderator for serious rule violations.

In this case, it was a self-deletion. (I can see that detail because I am a moderator. You would normally have no way of telling which case applied.)

Account deletion leaves nothing more than a “ghost”, with an anonymized name and avatar. The posts, however, remain intact, as do their scores and accepts, as a signal to other viewers of the posts’ quality and usefulness. (Except for negatively-scored posts, which are automatically deleted.)

Comment: I thought some of the content get removed at least in some cases (I believe upvoted content like shown in the post stays even in case of deletion due to misconduct)

Comment: @Alexei brb, deleting your account to confirm. In all seriousness, deletion removes all negatively scored content. It keeps zero-score and positively-scored posts. This is distinct from account *destruction*, which deletes everything and can only be done by moderators (for spammers).

Comment: Thanks @CodyGray I don't have an idea about the rule regarding that particular confusing question of mine. But anyway thanks for the explaination.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov this: [Change the delete user option so that it doesn't remove questions with upvoted answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/361876)